# PyQt4: disable deleting widget after setCentralWidget

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, python-sip

I have two custom widgets (two classes based on QtGui.QWidget). In `__init__` of QtGui.QMainWindow I create their instances:

```
self.MyWidget1 = MyWidget1()
self.MyWidget2 = MyWidget2()
```

There are also two buttons (QtGui.QPushButton) in `__init__` part, and there are two slots when user clicks each of them:

```
def clickButton1(self):
  self.setCentralWidget(self.MyWidget1)

def clickButton2(self):
  self.setCentralWidget(self.MyWidget2)
```

But it works only on first click and then PyQt says that underlying widget (MyWidget1 or MyWidget2) was deleted. I think it was done by **sip** module. Is there a way to prevent deleting widgets after reseting of central widget? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's almost impossible.

From [setCentralWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) docs:

> Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and **deletes** it at the appropriate time.

So, you should create new `MyWidget` instance.

```
def clickButton2(self):
    self.setCentralWidget(MyWidget2())
```

But the right way of doing such things is to use [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html)

Comment: `QStackedWidget` is really what I need! Thanks!